# Checkboxes that display results with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have the user check the boxes they are interested in getting resources for and then click the button to get a list of those resources that are hyperlinked to those resources. The hyperlinks (`ul id="results”` in HTML) are hidden until they called upon by the button “Get Resources”.

Plus I would like to add text to it before results saying  “You have indicated an interest in:” (line break) then a listing the hyperlinks (line break) “Please click on the links to learn more”. If no check box is selected the *div id=“alert”* displays, which I got to work.

I think I am very close, I just can’t seem to get the list of resources.

Here is a link to my coding:
[JSFiddle Code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/J_Wats/oagc50gy/)

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#alert').hide();
    $('#results > li').hide();

    /* Get the checkboxes values based on the parent div id */
    $("#resourcesButton").click(function() {
        getValue();
    });
});

function getValue(){
    var chkArray = [];

    /* look for all checkboxes that have a parent id called 'checkboxlist' attached to it and check if it was checked */
    $("#checkBoxes input:checked").each(function() {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    /* we join the array separated by the comma */
    var selected;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

    /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if(selected.length > 1){
        // Would like it to say something before and after what is displayed
        $('#results > li.' + $(this).attr('value')).show(); 
    } else {
        $('#alert').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The link for the original code above has been change [https://jsfiddle.net/J_Wats/ja5saabu/](https://jsfiddle.net/J_Wats/ja5saabu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd ditch the `selected` variable and just check the chkArray contents against the list item classes like:

```
function getValue() {
    var chkArray = [];
    /* look for all checkboxes that have a parent id called 'checkboxlist' attached to it and check if it was checked */
    $("#checkBoxes input:checked").each(function () {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#results li').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'), chkArray) > -1) $(this).show()
        else($(this).hide())
    })
    /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if (!chkArray.length) {
        $('#alert').show();
        //alert("Please at least one of the checkbox"); 
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oagc50gy/7/)**

Comment: This is great!  How would I though be able to add a phrase before the list of resources that says “You have indicated an interest in:” ,line break, then the list of resources hyperlinks, line break, then “Please click on the links to learn more."

Comment: You could add a couple of more divs hidden by default with the text you mentioned, both having the same CSS class, and then show them when links are displayed.

Comment: Ok, I added the CSS class .beforeAfter before and after the unordered list and  I hide it. But I'm having trouble figuring where to add the show when links are displayed coding.  Would it be possible show how and where the coding would go. And thanks, you’ve been supper helpful. I updated the  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J_Wats/oagc50gy/11/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a straightforward way of achieving what you want. DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/oagc50gy/8/

Here is my approach: I looped through all checkboxes. This way I could get the index of the current item in the original list, `i`, and use this index to display the corresponding item in the second list. I filter the checked items by using `.is(':checked')` condition, and then added them item to the array:

```
function getValue() {
    var chkArray = [];

    $("#checkBoxes input").each(function (i) {//now we can get the original index anytime

         if($(this).is(':checked')){//is the item checked?
             chkArray.push($(this).val());//if so add it to the array
             var selected;
             selected = chkArray.join(", ");

             if (selected.length) {
               $('#results').find('li').eq(i).show();//show the corresponding link by using `i`
             } else {
                  $('#alert').show();
             }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last thing in your `$(document).ready` function, add:

```
$("#checkBoxes input:checkbox").click(function() {
    $('li.' + $(this).val().replace(/ /g, '.')).show()
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/oagc50gy/10/)

*Explanation:*

On document ready, add a `click` handler to the checkboxes that `show`s the corresponding hidden list item below. The tricky thing here is the spaces in the list names. This makes each word a separate classname, so simply combine the list names with a dot `.` which results in a sequential classname call in jQuery.

By using `<li class="Fitness & Recreation">` as a list item classname, you are giving this item 3 classnames: `Fitness`, `&`, and `Recreation`. In jQuery you select elements with multiple classnames by including each name preceded by a dot `.`. For example, selecting a list item element with the classnames `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`:

```
$('li.foo.bar.baz').show()
```

In the case of `<li class="Fitness & Recreation">`:

```
$('li.Fitness.&.Recreation').show()
```

Since these values are stored in the `value` attribute of the checkboxes we use jQuery to pull these values: `$(this).val()`, replace the spaces with dots: `.replace(/ /g, '.')`, and concatenate the result to the `li.` portion to access the appropriate list item.